# A confusing question of probability.

Tags: probability, solution-verification

A father takes his son to the cinema.

- The child will ask to eat popcorn with probability $0.7$.
- In addition, he will ask to eat candy with probability $0.9$.
- These requests are accepted by the father with probability $0.5$, independently of each other.

How likely is it that the father will spend nothing but movie tickets?

$\underline{\mbox{My attempt}}$:

Consider the events.

$P$: the boy asks for popcorn;

$B$: the boy asks for a candy;

$A$: father fulfills the boy's request.

The probability that the father will spend something is

$$P((P \cap A) \cup (B \cap A)) = P(P\cap A) + P(B \cap A) - P(A \cap B \cap P),$$

as they are independent,

$$P((P \cap A) \cup (B \cap A)) = P(P)P(A) + P(B)P(A) - P(A)P(B)P(P) = 0.485.$$

Therefore, the probability that he will not spend anything is $1 - P((P \cap A) \cup (B \cap A)) = 0.515$, but the answer is $0.3575$.

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: What's a bullet in this context?

Comment: Sorry, I used a translator to speed up the process.

Comment: I figured, but I was curious what word for candy the translator rendered as "bullet".

Comment: In Portuguese, "bala = candy" and "bala = bullet". The translator only understands in context.

Comment: Anyway, to solve the problem:  The probability that the father pays nothing for popcorn is $.3+.7\times .5=.65$ (why?) and the probability that he pays nothing for candy is $.1+.9\times .5=.55$ (why?).  The answer is then $.65\times .55=.3575$

Comment: Thanks!  Bala is bullet in Spanish as well (I believe) but it isn't candy, so far as I know.

Comment: That's like *pellet* in English, which could be food or ammunition.

Comment: Note:  your method is misleading, at best, since you refer to $P(A\cap B\cap P)$ but $A$ is not a single event.  If the child requests both items then the father gets two chances to agree or not.

Comment: Yes, there should be two instances of $A$, say $A_B$ and $A_P$. (Probably best to rename $P$, since $P(P)$ starts to get confusing...)

Comment: @Théophile  Or, even "ball" I guess, since there are plenty of candies that come in balls.  Though it's been a while since rifles took "balls" and I don't think children ever ask for "balls" without specifying "gum balls" or the like.  But, still, the parallel is there.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Since you asked what you did wrong, you didn't include the probability that the kid asks for both and the father denies them both. That is $0.7 \cdot 0.9 \cdot 0.5 \cdot 0.5 = 0.1575$ which is exactly your error.

Answer (score 1):

Let the probability that the boy asks for popcorn be $p$, likewise let candy be $c$, and let the probability that the father **denies** any given request be $d$.

There are four possible ways the father could end up buying nothing:

1: The boy asks for popcorn and candy and the father denies both requests.

2: The boy asks for only popcorn and the father denies the request.

3: The boy asks for only candy and the father denies the request.

4: The boy asks for neither candy nor popcorn.

It is clear that if the boy does not ask for something, the probability that the father denies the request is of no importance: there is no request to deny. Also, the probability that the boy does not ask for popcorn is $1-p$, and likewise $1-c$ for candy. So, the probability of each case is:
$$\mathrm{P}(\text{Case 1})=p\cdot d\cdot c\cdot d$$
$$\mathrm{P}(\text{Case 2})=p\cdot d\cdot (1-c)$$
$$\mathrm{P}(\text{Case 3})=(1-p)\cdot c\cdot d$$
$$\mathrm{P}(\text{Case 4})=(1-p)(1-c)$$
So in total, the probability that the father does not buy the boy anything is the sum across all cases:
$$\mathrm{P}(\text{Father buys boy nothing})= p\cdot d\cdot c\cdot d + p\cdot d\cdot (1-c) + (1-p)\cdot c\cdot d+(1-p)(1-c)$$
Plugging in $p=0.7$, $c=0.9$, and $d=0.5$ and crunching the numbers this turns out to be $0.3575$.